# SAPUI5 add element on top of a VBox

Tags: sapui5

I am creating ObjectStatus and Text elements in my controller in order to add them into a VBox element in my view. I do this with the addItem method. Every new element is automatically placed on the very bottom of the VBox. How can I achieve that the new element is added on the top of the VBox instead (above the elements I added before)? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can you select an answer or give more information on what you exactly need. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
this.byId("vbox").insertItem(oControl);
```

instead of:

```
this.byId("vbox").addItem(oControl);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `direction` property (inherited from [FlexBox](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.FlexBox/controlProperties)) of your `VBox` control to [`ColumnReverse`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.FlexDirection).

Alternatively, as pointed out by Matthijs, you can use [`insertItem()`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.FlexBox/methods/insertItem) instead of `addItem()`. That would also allow precise placement within the aggregation using the `iIndex` parameter.

Answer (score -3):

Here's is another suggestion:

1. You can get all the items of the VBox in an array.
2. Remove items from the VBox
3. Place your new item at first position in the VBox.
4. Add stored VBox items with from the array.

```js
//Add some items initially to the VBox
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  this.getView().byId("idVBox").addItem(new sap.m.Text({
    text: "SomeText2"
  }));
}

//Get the items of the Vbox
var array = this.getView().byId("idVBox").getItems();

//remove all items
this.getView().byId("idVBox").removeAllItems();

//add your new item as the first item to the VBox
this.getView().byId("idVBox").addItem(new sap.m.Text({
  id: "someOtherid",
  text: "SomeText2New"
}));

//add all the others back
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  this.getView().byId("idVBox").addItem(array[i]);
```

Comment: Considering the other options already proposed, this requires a lot of unnecessary code.